# Arch Linux system borked after update

Tags: arch-linux, boot, wifi, macintosh

I have been running arch on my macbook 5,2 since I purchased it back in 2009. This morning I did a full system update (after a few months going without updates) and found some things not working, specifically:

1. 'nobody cared' on IRQs 9 to 11, the first time this happened three years ago adding a 'irqpoll' option to the boot command line fixed this problem. This time however, the problem does not go away (the system still asks to put irqpoll on the command line).
2. wireless does not work. I rebuilt broadcom-wl after the update, but it caused a kernel panic at the next boot.

I tried searching the usual resources (wiki, bbs, ...) but found no answer. Can anybody help..?

EDIT: nevermind, the problem seemed to fix itself after rebooting to mac and then back to arch again...

Comment: oops, mistyped tag 'macintosh', should be 'macbook'. I can't seem to change it, admins..?

Comment: They're synonymous (see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/macintosh/info)).

Comment: "Not a real question" and "Too localized".